# Same output for different images during prediction with Quantized MobilenetV1 Tf-lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am following the example at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/person_detection/training_a_model.md

I have different input images; however, the output is always same when it is predicted with same tflite model/file. My code sample and output is below.

What am I missing?

Tflite file Quantized as:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph('vww_96_grayscale_frozen.pb', ['input'], ['MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1'])
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

Inference Code:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=TFLITE_MODEL)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

for cnt in range(5):
    image_path = "/data/0-val_img-"+str(cnt)+".png"
    image_data = PIL.Image.open(image_path).resize((96, 96)).convert('L')    

    #plt.imshow(image_data)  # shows different images, as expected
    #plt.show()

    array = np.array(image_data).astype(np.uint8)
    array = ((array / 127.5) - 1.0).astype(np.float32)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=2)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)

 
    # set input data
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], array)
    interpreter.invoke()
    # get output
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    print(output_data)
```

Output

```
[[0.91796875 0.08203125]]
[[0.91796875 0.08203125]]
[[0.91796875 0.08203125]]
[[0.91796875 0.08203125]]
[[0.91796875 0.08203125]]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think problem was low number of epochs in my training. I retrained the network with 200000 epochs. All images generate a different probability values as expected.